# How convert the char ' to \' in android?

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to convert a string  "hello i'm the boss" to "hello i\'m the boss"
how can i do this please

my problem is to convert ' to \'

somebody have an idea please??

```
String a="hello i'm the boss";
```

i need

```
result="hello i\'m the boss"
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use replace as follows:

```
String result = a.replace("'","\\'");
```

Note that the original `String a` will not be affected by this operation.

Answer (score 0):

\\ should give you the \ character in the string

```
String x = "Hello I\\'m the boss"
```